# Code First EF Model Issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Running into an issue where looking at `Group.Members.Count()` is coming back at 0.

```
public class Employee
{  
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; } 
    public Guid? PrimaryGroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrimaryGroupId")]
    public virtual Group PrimaryGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}


public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? GroupOwnerId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupOwnerId")]
    public virtual Employee GroupOwner{ get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Members{ get; set; } 
}
```

Essentially, an `Employee` will have a primary group and only 1 primary group.  This is nullable because not all employees will be in a group.  A Group can have 1 employee who is the group owner, but also a collection of employees who call this group their "primary" group.

Have a requirement in a view for a user to see how many employees call that group their primary.  I'm utilizing this code: `Group.Members.Count()` but get 0 as a result despite the data clearly being different.  Also appears as though EF/Code First is generating secondary columns for these relationships as there is now a FK column `PrimaryGroup_Id` appearing.

This is what the migration is generating for the model....

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Employees",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            Name = c.String(),
            IsActive = c.Boolean(nullable: false), 
            PrimaryGroupId= c.Guid(),
            PrimaryGroup_Id = c.Guid(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Groups", t => t.PrimaryGroupId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Groups", t => t.PrimaryGroup_Id)
    .Index(t => t.PrimaryGroupId)
    .Index(t => t.PrimaryGroup_Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Groups",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            Name = c.String(),
            IsActive = c.Boolean(nullable: false), 
            GroupOwnerId= c.Guid(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Employees", t => t.GroupOwnerId)
    .Index(t => t.GroupOwnerId);
```

The crazy thing is that both of the PrimaryGroupId columns exist on the Employee table, if after editing an employee I copy the GUID from that record to the PrimaryGroup_Id column, the count on the Groups view does go up.  Feels like a FK problem of some kind.

Comment: Have you Include()'ed the table? Do you have lazy loading enabled?

Comment: The include is there on the select.  With lazy loading not being there, my code would throw exceptions as I call Groups.Employees.Count() which Employees would be NULL.  

It appears the issue is getting 2 columns rather than 1 for PrimaryGroupId.

Answer (score 0):

EF must be having trouble linking `Members` to `PrimaryGroupId` so help it out by explicitly declaring the inverse navigation property: `[ForeignKey("PrimaryGroupId"), InverseProperty("Members")]`.

If I copy your code (excluding `Addresses`, `PhoneNumbers`, and `Activities` properties) I do get the additional Id property but it is called `Group_Id`:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Employees",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    PrimaryGroupId = c.Guid(),
                    Group_Id = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey( "dbo.Groups", t => t.Group_Id)
            .ForeignKey( "dbo.Groups", t => t.PrimaryGroupId)
            .Index(t => t.PrimaryGroupId)
            .Index(t => t.Group_Id);
```

If I add `InverseProperty("Members")` as described above, I get:

```
         CreateTable(
            "dbo.Employees",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    PrimaryGroupId = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Groups", t => t.PrimaryGroupId)
            .Index(t => t.PrimaryGroupId);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523686/unable-to-determine-the-principal-end-of-an-association

Comment: Yes, that is the same issue. Adding the annotation fixes your problem no?